# Review of batch file?

Tags: file, batch-file

hi i'm looking to see if someone can review my batch file i made...the choice command is not working...thanks for your help
(running win8)
here is the code

```
@echo off
echo welcome to Vip3r coding and programming Antivirus install wizard
pause
echo Express Install 
echo Custom Install (WIP)
set /p choice=Express installation or install with custom setings? (type Express or Custom)
if not '%choice%'== set choice=%choice:~0,1%
if '%choice%'=='Express' goto :choice1
if '%choice%'=='Custom' goto :choice1
:choice 1
pause
cls
color 04
echo you shouldn't have done that
pause
cls
msg* Backd00r install complete
```

Answer (score 1):

"Not working" is a meaningless description. If it **was** "working", you'd not be asking a question, would you? You need to tell us what **actually** happened and what you **expected** to happen - otherwise, we're guessing.

Nonetheless, you need to understand the `if` statement

```
if not '%choice%'== set choice=%choice:~0,1%
if '%choice%'=='Express' goto :choice1
if '%choice%'=='Custom' goto :choice1
```

`IF` requires four elements. Two arguments to compare, a comparison operator and something-to-do-if-the-comparison-is-true.

```
if not '%choice%'== set choice=%choice:~0,1%
```

will compare `'%choice%'` to `set` and if **not** equal (==) then execute `choice=%choice:~0,1%`.

Regardless of the value of `choice`, `'%choice%'` will never be equal to `set`, so the comand `choice=%choice:~0,1%` will be executed - and that's an invalid command.

If you want to know whether `choice` is set to *any value* then you could use

```
if '%choice%'=='' set something
```

or

```
if "%choice%"=="" set something
```

or (my preference)

```
if defined choice set something
```

the single quotes are simply 'comfortable'. The idea is to ensure that both sides of the `==` operator are **exactly** the same **and** not empty. Some people use `x` or `.` or some other symbol - and not necessarily "matched". All that is required is that the two strings *may* match.

The double-quotes version is better because `cmd` regards a string between double-quotes as a single item, so should the user type `some response including spaces` then `"%choice%"` will be regarded as a single string.

("choice" by the way, is a poor, if logical, er - choice - for a variable name since `choice` is a `cmd` keyword)

The `if defined` method is stronger still (and quicker to type.) It doesn't care what the value is - just whether or not the value exists.

The other two lines - well no actual problems - but remember the <kbd>'</kbd> vs <kbd>"</kbd> issue. The colon in a `goto` is not necessary (or, IMHO desirable) but harmless.

The problem with the code is that you havn't taken care of the possibility that the string typed is neither of the strings specified. Batch has no concept of 'sections' or 'procedures' - a label is simply a marker, no more - and hence it will contine on, line by line until it reaches end-of-file or a `goto` statement (but may be persuaded to take a little detour with a `call`)

Hence, even if neither of the strings you've specified matches, the procedure will progress to the very next statement which is the `choice1` routine.

Comment: edit* i was expecting it to be so that if you type express or custom it would go to the choice one command set and continue with the batch file as for what happens whenever i type Express or Custom it closes faster than i can read it 

P.S i am an absolute NOOB so i didn't understand what you said in your post

Comment: @SgtVip3r for troubleshooting don't run by DoubleClick, but open a command prompt window and execute it from there, so the window stays open to read any errormessages. Also remove `@echo off` to see, what's really executed.

Answer (score 0):

regarding `the choice command is not working`: you don't use a `choice` command, but there actually *is* a [choice](https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) command - which even is much better here than your `set /p` approach, because it only will accept defined keys:

```
@echo off
choice /c EC /N /M "Express installation or install with custom setings?  [E]xpress or [C]ustom: "
call :label%errorlevel%
echo done.
pause
goto :eof


:label1 [Express]
echo express install
goto :eof

:label2 [Custom]
echo custom install
goto :eof
```